# Proof of well-ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ using modified induction and contraposition.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, predicate-logic

This question regards an alternative proof of the theorem of well-ordering
of $\mathbb{N},$ using a modified principle of induction and contraposition,
found on page 101 of [Fundamentals of Mathematics, Volume 1 Foundations of Mathematics: The Real Number System and Algebra; Edited by H. Behnke, F. Bachmann, K. Fladt, W. Suess and H. Kunle](https://archive.org/stream/MyStuff38/Behnke%2C%20Bachmann%2C%20Fladt%20%26%20Suss%20[Eds.]%20-%20Fundamentals%20of%20Mathematics%20Vol.1%2C%20The%20Real%20Number%20System%20and%20Algebra[MIT%20Press%2C%20555p]#page/n7/mode/2up).

The square brackets following quantifiers indicate the scope of the bound variables.  The way I read my notation is, for example:

$$
\forall_{n<m}\left[n\in\mathcal{M}\right]
$$

*For all $n$ less than $m$, $n$ is an element of $\mathcal{M}$.*

**The question: Is the following proof correct?**

The **modified principle of induction** is: *If the number $m$ is contained
in the number set $\mathcal{M}$ whenever $n\in\mathcal{M}$ for all
numbers $n<m$, then $\mathcal{M}=\mathbb{N}.$*

The **theorem of well-ordering of the natural numbers** is: *Every nonempty set of natural numbers contains a smallest number.*

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

> As another method of proving the same theorem, we note that, if we
>   replace $\mathcal{M}$ by the set $\mathbb{N}-\mathcal{M}$ of the
>   numbers not in $\mathcal{M},$ our modified principle of induction
>   can be transformed, by contraposition and other purely logical operations,
>   into the desired theorem of well-ordering of the natural numbers.

One form of the contrapositive of implication is:

$$
\left(p\implies q\iff\lnot q\implies\lnot p\right).
$$

The modified principle of induction is formalized as

$$
\forall_{m}\left[\forall_{n<m}\left[n\in\mathcal{M}\right]\Rightarrow m\in\mathcal{M}\right]\Rightarrow\mathcal{M}=\mathbb{N}.
$$

Rename $\mathcal{M}\mapsto\overline{\mathcal{M}}$ and write the result
as the contrapositive of the original expression, followed by some
transformations

$$
\overline{\mathcal{M}}\neq\mathbb{N}\Rightarrow\lnot\left(\forall_{m}\left[\forall_{n<m}\left[n\in\mathcal{M}\right]\Rightarrow m\in\mathcal{M}\right]\right)
$$

$$
\iff\overline{\mathcal{M}}\subset\mathbb{N}\Rightarrow\exists_{m}\left[\neg\left(\forall_{n<m}\left[n\in\overline{\mathcal{M}}\right]\Rightarrow m\in\overline{\mathcal{M}}\right)\right]
$$

$$
\iff\overline{\mathcal{M}}\subset\mathbb{N}\Rightarrow\exists_{m}\left[\forall_{n<m}\left[n\in\overline{\mathcal{M}}\right]\land m\notin\overline{\mathcal{M}}\right].
$$

Now define $\overline{\mathcal{M}}\equiv\mathbb{N}-\mathcal{M},$
and replace $\overline{\mathcal{M}}\mapsto\mathcal{M}$ according
to that meaning

$$
\emptyset\ne\mathcal{M}\subseteq\mathbb{N}\Rightarrow\exists_{m}\left[\forall_{n<m}\left[n\notin\mathcal{M}\right]\land m\in\mathcal{M}\right].
$$

This statement reads: That $\mathcal{M}$ is a non-empty subset of
$\mathbb{N}$ implies the existence of $m$ such that for all $n<m$
we have $n\notin\mathcal{M}$ and $m\in\mathcal{M}.$ That is $m$
is the smallest element of $m.$

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently others affirm the validity of my proof, and I believe it to be formally correct, so my answer is: Yes the proof is correct.

For anybody who uses this proof, I urge him or her to explore its meaning by considering special cases such as $\mathcal{M}=\left\{n\backepsilon n>m\right\},$ etc.